# How can I create a controller for polymorphic association using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, polymorphic-associations, vote-up-buttons

I have created a feed_item using this migration

```
class CreateFeeds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :feeds do |t|
      t.integer :item_id
      t.string :item_type
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
end
```

and I am displaying the content of the feed like

photos
    = image_tag feed.item.image_url

post
    = feed.item.text

I trying to add a vote button so the migration for the vote model looks like

```
class CreateVotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :votes do |t|
      t.integer :votable_id
      t.string :votable_type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :votable, polymorphic: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes, as: :votable
end
```

How do I create the vote controller's create action?

I tried

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @votable = find_votable
    @vote = @votable.votes.build(params[:vote])
  end

  private
    def find_votable
      params.each do |name, value|
        if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
          return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
        end
      end
      nil
    end

    def vote_params
      params.require(:vote).permit(:votable)
    end
end
```

and got undefined metheod "votes"

also tried

```
@vote = params[:votable_type].classify.constantize.find(params[:votable_type])
```

I got undefined metheod "classify"

Comment: I guess you have a typo here. 
Colon missing in params[votable_type].

Comment: undefined method for what? for nil?

Comment: added colon but still nothing

Comment: undefined method like I am suppose to define the method or like can't find method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't use a VotesController, you would create votes via other models which have a polymorphic relationship with them.  In your example above, you would create them via:

```
post.votes
```

*(assuming `post` was an instance of `Post`)*

The idea behind polymorphic relationships is a many-to-many relationship with multiple models, so you should be creating any 'votable' records via the source models, in this example, `Post`.

For instance, you could create a `vote` method in your `PostController` that would create the vote association as I've outlined above and then add the appropriate route to submit your voting form.

Additionally, your `Vote` model could also contain other data, depending on how you want to use voting.  For instance, if you wanted to track the number of votes a model gets, you could add a `count` column.  In which case, you would create the record as:

```
post.votes.count += 1
```

Comment: Can you explain that in more details please. My vote button calls the vote's create action.